# PHP variable into mySQL table: not working?

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

This is similar to a question I asked a while ago, however this didn't seem to attract any answers so I'll try again.

I have a booking system which you log into, and your username is stored in a cookie named `$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']`. I have a script which runs after a user has booked their flight which stores all the details into a table (named `OABS_customers`), which works fine, however the one row which doesn't work is the `username` row, which adds `$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` into the row.

The table's structure is the following:

```
Name         Type(Length)    Null     Default

name         varchar(60)     No       noname
address1     varchar(60)     No       noaddress
address2     varchar(60)     No       noaddress2
county       varchar(60)     No       nocounty
postcode     varchar(32)     No       nopostcode
customer     tinyint(4)      No       
seats        varchar(11)     No       0
number       tinyint(4)      No       0
class        varchar(11)     No       noclass
username     varchar(60)     No       nousername
```

So like I said, everything works fine but the `username` column, which just comes up with the default value of `nousername`. This is the code I am using;

`$query = "INSERT INTO OABS_customers (username) VALUES ('$user')";`

where `$user = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` (defined before the above script).

If anyone could help out with this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what is the value of `$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` when you assign it to `$user`?

Comment: when you echo $user what is the result?

Comment: Standard php/sql debugging regime: Print the query and spot-check for obvious errors. Take the query and run it in manually. Still can't find the issue? Make sure you're selecting the right database and the user has the correct privileges.

Comment: debug the $query variable and try to verify the $user by adding isset to it.thanks

Comment: Just in case your query is within a function and the $user variable is declared globally outside of the function you need to make sure that you pull it into your function using global $user;

Comment: Don't put dynamic values into SQL queries. Use [prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) in mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Never* put unescaped, user generated strings into SQL queries. The cookies could be altered by some evil user and this leads to an SQL injection. Use `mysql_real_escape_string($user)` to escape the string.

Make sure that `$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` is not empty

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO OABS_customers (username) VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($user) ."')");
```

Comment: +1 for stressing the importance of SQL Injection. However, please keep in mind that the mysql extension and the `mysql_` functions are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) and mysqli or PDO should be used and recommended instead.

Comment: You are right. With `mysqli_` you are able to use prepared statements and `mysql_real_escape_string()` becomes obsolete.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is finally working somewhat now, and of course is more secure. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with MySQL query...

```
mysql> INSERT INTO data (username) VALUES ('random');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> select * from data;
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | random   |
+----+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Looks like `$COOKIE` value is empty, and when you perform query PHP assigns empty string to `username` value. MySQL see that empty value is passed and writes default value to `username` column